# MongoDB Nesting or Splitting Best Practices

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I wanted to know if anyone knew if you can over use embedding on MongoDB. Not saying something like 100 levels deep, in my application my average document size can get pretty large, simple tests have shown documents of 177kb.

The application is for logging, so for example I take the Apache access log and get lots of things from it like a list of all the pages that were called, a lit of all the IP address and so on. And these are done by minute.

It is unlikely that that I would ever have a document that was at the MongoDB document size limit, but wanted to know if I keep each of the sub lists as there own document, would that make for better performance regarding, returning subset information (querying for all the IP addresses that took place over 5 minutes).

When I run the query I filter to only show the IP addresses, am I wasting the databases performance if I group each minute into one document, or am I wasting it if I split each list into its own document?

Answer (score 2):

You want to structure your collections and documents in a way that reflects how you intend to use the data. If you're going to do a lot of complex queries, especially with subdocuments, you might find it easier to split your documents up into separate collections. An example of this would be splitting comments from blog posts.

Your comments could be stored as an array of subdocuments:

```
# Example post document with comment subdocuments
{
    title: 'How to Mongo!'
    content: 'So I want to talk about MongoDB.',
    comments: [
        {
            author: 'Renold',
            content: 'This post, it's amazing.'
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

This might cause problems, though, if you want to do complex queries on just comments (e.g. picking the most recent comments from *all* posts or getting all comments by one author.) If you plan on making these complex queries, you'd be better off creating two collections: one for comments and the other for posts.

```
# Example post document with "ForeignKeys" to comment documents
{
    _id: ObjectId("50c21579c5f2c80000000000"),
    title: 'How to Mongo!',
    content: 'So I want to talk about MongoDB.',
    comments: [
        ObjectId("50c21579c5f2c80000000001"),
        ObjectId("50c21579c5f2c80000000002"),
        ...
    ]
}

# Example comment document with a "ForeignKey" to a post document
{
    _id: ObjectId("50c21579c5f2c80000000001"),
    post_id: ObjectId("50c21579c5f2c80000000000"),
    title: 'Renold',
    content: 'This post, it's amazing.'
}
```

This is similar to how you'd store "ForeignKeys" in a relational database. Normalizing your documents like this makes for querying both comments and posts easy. Also, since you're breaking up your documents, each document will take up less memory. The trade-off, though, is you have to maintain the `ObjectId` references whenever there's a change to either document (e.g. when you insert/update/delete a comment or post.) And since there are no event hooks in Mongo, you have to do all this maintenance in your application.

On the other-hand, if you don't plan on doing any complex queries on a document's subdocuments, you might benefit from storing monolithic objects. For instance, a user's preferences isn't something you're likely to make queries for:

```
# Example user document with address subdocument
{
    ObjectId("50c21579c5f2c800000000421"),
    name: 'Howard',
    password: 'naughtysecret',
    address: {
        state: 'FL',
        city: 'Gainesville',
        zip: 32608
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Because my system is a logging system, once documents are inserted they will never change, some will get deleted but that will be handled buy ttl 99.999% of the time. I was thinking that I could store both the master document, and the child document into the same collection. so when I need to do a query i can do an Or statment to get master and child and if i know i dont need one type of document i can then do a $nin query there. But i am not sure if thats getting to complex for mongo and better to just do the "monolithic object"

Comment: Why don't you try making the queries you plan to make on a dummy schema to see how complicated those queries might be? If your structure makes querying difficult, try rejiggering it until you arrive at a structure that's simple to work with. Doing a little bit of this upfront planning/prototyping work will make developing your system much easier down the road.